# wrap an element without jquery

Tags: javascript, wrapper

I have some code like this in my page:

```
    <div class="kg-gallery-image" style="flex: 0.708889 1 0%;">
<img src="photo.jpg"></div>
```

I want to change them on fly to this without using jquery:

```
    <div class="kg-gallery-image" style="flex: 0.6665 1 0%;">
<a data-fslightbox="" href="photo.jpg"><img src="photo"></a></div>
```

What I need is, get img tag inside kg-gallery-image & wrap around it:

```
<a data-fslightbox="" href=""></a>
```

But I need it to get the scr of img tag & put it for href of the a tag.

I used this jquery code:

```
<script>
$('.kg-gallery-image img ').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<a data-no-swup data-fslightbox href='" + this.src + "'/>");
});
</script>
```

which work great, but as I don't use any other function from jquery, I want to try creating this code with pure js,
is there any way to create this with pure js?

I had created something like this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.kg-gallery-image img')).forEach((el) => {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('a');
  var imgSource = document.querySelector('.kg-gallery-image img').src;
  wrapper.href=""+imgSource;
 wrapper.setAttribute('data-fslightbox', 'data-fslightbox');

  el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
  wrapper.appendChild(el);
});
```

But it add href of the first image to all a tag.

Comment: _"is there any way to create this with pure js?"_ - Sure. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: `.createElement()` and `.appendChild()` might be handy

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I can't figure how to get img src & add it inside a tag

Comment: I just edited my original question.

Comment: `el` is the image -> `el.src`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, Solved

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.kg-gallery-image img')).forEach((el) => {  
  var wrapper = document.createElement('a');
  wrapper.setAttribute('data-fslightbox', 'data-fslightbox');
  wrapper.href=""+el.src;
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
  wrapper.appendChild(el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

1. Get Parent element inside which you want to add `a` tag
2. Create `a` element using `createElement`
3. Get `img` using `src
4. Append child using `appendChild`

```js
var parentElem = document.getElementsByClassName("kg-gallery-image");
var achorElem = document.createElement("a");
var imgElem = document.querySelector("img[src='photo.jpg']");
achorElem.href=""+imgElem.src;
parentElem[0].appendChild(achorElem);
achorElem.appendChild(imgElem);
```

```html
<div class="kg-gallery-image" style="flex: 0.708889 1 0%;">
<img src="photo.jpg"></div>
```

```js
    var parentElem = $(".kg-gallery-image");
    var achorElem = document.createElement("a");
   // var imgElem = document.querySelector("img[src='photo.jpg']");
   var imgElem = $("img");
    achorElem.href=""+imgElem.attr("src");
    //parentElem[0].appendChild(achorElem);
    //achorElem.appendChild(imgElem); 
    imgElem.wrap(achorElem);
```

```html
 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

       <div class="kg-gallery-image" style="flex: 0.708889 1 0%;">
    <img src="photo.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, This exactly my problem, I cant figure how to wrap the a element around the img

Comment: don't forget to accept answer if this helpful. You should give some code which try till. @MoeenSalehi

Comment: Yes, actually this code is not working for me, @aviboy2006

Comment: you can try running here in "Run code Snippet". what issue are you facing ?

Comment: I want to replicate this .wrap function of jquery with only js:

Comment: $('.kg-gallery-image img ').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<a data-no-swup data-fslightbox href='" + this.src + "'/>");
});

Comment: you can do with javascript also.

Comment: Added jquery code. your above code is also working. what is issue in this ?

Comment: I think I explain my problem bad, I want to create a code that do something like .wrap function in jquery, for some reason I can't use jquery in my site, so I need a pure JS way to do something like warp function.

Comment: i added pure javascript code only without using jquery. Please check that part. you ask jQuery so i added jQuery code also.

Comment: Thanks, I checked again, It doesn't do what I tried to do, it should get img tag inside the class, wrap around it an a tag with the data attribute, and replace to old img tag with new <new a><old img></> for all the page.